# shell: addition from lines in an string

Tags: shell, awk, addition

Let's say I have a variable like this:

`list='1
1
1.4
1
1
1'`

Now I want to add the value from each line to the value from the line before. Like this:

`result='1
2
3.4
4.4
5.4'`

It must work with floating numbers too, so I guess awk is the best tool for it.

I was stating with a while loop:

```
while read line; do 
    add=$( awk 'BEGIN{ print "'"$x"'" + "'"$line"'" }' ) 
done <<< "$list"
```

But this doesn't work because I don't know how to save the value from the line before.

Comment: What did you try already that you ended up asking for help? Where is your code which does not work?

Comment: I was stating with a while loop:
`
while read line; do
  add=$( awk 'BEGIN{ print "'"$x"'" + "'"$line"'" }' )
done <<< "$list" 
`
But this don't work, because I don't know how to save the value from line befor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my `bash` snippet:

```
prev=0
for val in $list; do
  val=$(echo "$val + $prev"|bc)
  prev=$val
  result="${result}${val}\n"
done
echo -e "$result"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether using `zsh` (which has floating point support) is an option, but if it is, you can simply do:

```
s=0;for i in $list; do s=$(($s+$i)); echo $s; done
```

Comment: Thank you, I have try this example, but using awk, for calculation. It looks good, but after the operation I have no float numbers anymore.

Comment: The code is like this:
`s=0; for i in ${startTime}; do s=$( awk 'BEGIN{ print "'"$s"'"+"'"$i"'"}' ); echo "$s"; done`. The interesting thing is, that the same is with anubhava example. Maybe is a OS issue because on Ubuntu I get floating numbers, but not accurate and in OSX, where I write the script I don't get floats.

Comment: Interesting. I cannot test this on OSX myself, in linux it works as expected. Maybe there is another version of awk on OSX?

Comment: Yes I think so. The number on Linux I get rounded to one decimal place, and OSX round it to full numbers. The script have to run on Linux, so I am fine with that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it using `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
list='1
1
1.4
1
1
1'

results=( )
total="0.0"
index=0
for line in $list; do
   total=$(bc -l <<< "$line + $total")
   echo $total
   results[$index]=$total
   let index++
done

echo ${results[@]}
```

Also:

```
total="0.0"; while read v; do total=$(bc -l <<< "$v + $total"); echo $total; done <<< "$list"
```

Comment: I have try this, but with that I only get the total of all numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the intermediate result storage, what about now?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1{print; s=$1; next} {s+=$1; print s}' file
1
2
3.4
4.4
5.4
6.4
```